# TIempos de ejecución muy altos en instancias aleatorias GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp

Estoy trabajando en disminuir el tiempo de ejecución de algunas instancias de Google Cloud Platform.

El problema es que cuando llegan una cantidad considerable de peticiones HTTP, algunas de las instancias que se levantan extremadamente más lentas que otras (todas son la misma función):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El rectángulo rojo agrupa las instancias que considero outliers: aquellas que tardan muchísimo más tiempo que otras. La que se encuentra en un círculo rojo es la misma que las que se encuentran en el rectángulo, pero tarda menos de la mitad del tiempo.
Sin embargo, pasado un tiempo deja de suceder y todas tardan practicamente lo mismo.
Entiendo que al inicio (cold start) tarde algo más que cuando ya se han levantado, pero estos outliers se escapan totalmente del resto.
El uso de recursos nunca llega al límite, ya que la memoria asignada para la función son 256MB.
¿A qué podría deberse?
Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias posibles razones por las que algunas instancias de GCP pueden tardar más en iniciarse que otras, incluso si están ejecutando la misma función:

1. Puede ser que las instancias que tardan más en iniciarse estén alojadas en nodos físicos con una carga más alta, lo que puede ralentizar el inicio de las funciones.
2. Es posible que algunas instancias tengan una mayor latencia de red, lo que puede retrasar la comunicación entre los componentes que forman la función.
3. Otra posibilidad es que algunas instancias tengan que cargar módulos o librerías adicionales que no están presentes en las otras instancias. Esto podría retrasar el inicio de la función.
4. Por último, aunque la memoria asignada para la función es de 256MB, es posible que algunas instancias estén utilizando más recursos que otras (por ejemplo, si están procesando cargas de trabajo más pesadas), lo que podría ralentizar el inicio de la función.

Para hacer troubleshooting, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

- Aumentar la cantidad de memoria asignada para la función, ya que esto puede mejorar el rendimiento de la función y reducir el tiempo de inicio.
- Utilizar una imagen personalizada que incluya todas las bibliotecas y dependencias necesarias para la función, lo que puede reducir el tiempo de inicio al evitar la necesidad de cargar módulos adicionales.
- Utilizar un plan de precios de función prewarming que garantice que siempre haya instancias disponibles para manejar la carga entrante, lo que puede reducir el tiempo de inicio y mejorar la latencia.
- Por último, puedes revisar los registros de GCP para identificar cualquier problema o cuello de botella en el proceso de inicio de la función.